# Create Helper to choose specific maps depending on input

Tags: java, collections

I'm unsure of how to best design for the following problem

```
Map<String, Person> dataSource1_Map1 = {fill this map up from data source1}
Map<String, Student> dataSource1_Map2 = {fill this map up from data source1}
Map<String, Person> dataSource2_Map1 = {fill this map up from data source2}
Map<String, Student> dataSource2_Map2 = {fill this map up from data source2}
```

(The Maps live in a class whose object is accessible everywhere)

My code which requires these maps dosen't need to know what data source filled the map.

I was thinking on the lines of

```
//DataMaps contains two maps - Map<String,Person> & Map<String,Student>
DataMaps maps = DataSourceHelper.getMaps(values that help determine source)
doStuff(maps);

getMaps(input values)
{
  if(values -> data source1)
  return data source1 maps
  else
  return data source2 maps
}
```

I'm unsure of how best to design the DataMaps & DataSourceHelper or whether there is a better way of designing for this problem.

Comment: Well, if both maps in each datasource are coupled then without knowing more it seems ok to use `DataMaps` (although the name might be a bit more specifc due to the class containing maps of persons and students).

Comment: This approach will cost you more memory consumption (for nothing). Why not to use just a List of maps, e.g.:    public void doStuff(ArrayList<Map> allMaps) { for(Map map:allMaps) doStuff(map); }

Comment: @bohuss, I only need one set of maps at a time. Also they are not iteratively called as in your code.